# What does "System library (added to the boot class path)" means in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

What is the meaning of ***"System library (added to the boot class path)"*** when we create ***user library*** in Eclipse.

[image: System library (added to the boot class path) image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Means it will be included in the classpath prior to other classes as if your library were part of the Java runtime. For a more specific and detailed explanation, you can check the Oracle doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html

Comment: thanks for replying, I am confused whether it will be included in Windows/ Unix classpath or its scope will be only Eclipse.

Comment: Here it's explained: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20083696/eclipse-created-user-library-with-hibernate-jars-to-the-project-as-system-libr